# Using LINQ to find duplicate min values in array C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array with 15 employees and i want to show in a listbox the employee with the lowest salary. But when i have more than one employees with the same low salary it only prints one of them 15 times. Can you tell me how can i print all the employees with the lowest salary? The code is at the lowestSalaryCheck() method.

```
namespace ProgrammingAssignment
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Employee[] myEmployee = new Employee[15];
        public string theFirst;
        public string theLast;
        public int theID;
        public double theSalary;
        public bool continueLoop;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void addEmployees()
        {
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    theFirst = Convert.ToString(firstBox.Text);
                    theLast = Convert.ToString(lastBox.Text);
                    theID = Convert.ToInt32(idBox.Text);
                    theSalary = Convert.ToDouble(salaryBox.Text);

                    if (theFirst.Length > 0 && theLast.Length > 0 && theID > 0 && theSalary > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < myEmployee.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Employee emp = new Employee(theFirst, theLast, theID, theSalary);
                            myEmployee[i] = emp;
                        }
                    }
                    continueLoop = false;
                }
                catch (DivideByZeroException dz)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(dz.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine("Zero is an invalid number.");
                }
                catch (FormatException fe)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(fe.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine("Please add a valid number.");
                }

            } while (continueLoop);
        }

        private void lowestSalaryCheck()
        {
            var theSal = myEmployee.Min(em => em.yearlySalary);
            var theMin = myEmployee.Where(em => em.yearlySalary == theSal);

            foreach (var emp in theMin)
            {
                string message = string.Format("Lowest Salary: {0} {1} {2} {3}", emp.firstName, emp.lastName, emp.id, theSal);
                lowestList.Items.Add(message);
            }
        }

        private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            addEmployees();
        }

        private void lowestSalary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lowestSalaryCheck();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't really tell what's wrong without seeing your `Employee` code. It's very odd that you've got a console app that also appears to be a form though... ideally, reduce this to a [mcve]. A pure console app would be simpler for that. (Also, please learn about formatting code in SO - see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Your code should work as desired. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @SándorMátyásMárton Well, ordering is O(n log n), while finding the minimum and filtering for it is O(n), so there are good reasons for the latter.

Comment: Also, I have no idea what the purpose of ˛`continueLoop` is - I think you should get rid of the `do...while` loop and the `continueLoop` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a new `Employee`, you seem to replace all existing `Employee`s in your list to the newly added one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myEmployee.Length; i++)
{
    Employee emp = new Employee(theFirst, theLast, theID, theSalary);
    myEmployee[i] = emp;
}
```

This loop runs 15 times every time you call your `addEmployees` function and replaces every element of your `myEmployee` array to a newly created `Employee`.

In my opinion, you should use dynamic collections, so instead of `Employee[] myEmployee = new Employee[15];` you could use `List<Employee> myEmployee = new ArrayList<Employee>();`

Then instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i < myEmployee.Length; i++)
{
    Employee emp = new Employee(theFirst, theLast, theID, theSalary);
    myEmployee[i] = emp;
}
```

You could use

```
Employee emp = new Employee(theFirst, theLast, theID, theSalary);
myEmployee.Add(emp);
```

Your code should work after this, as I can see no problem with your LINQ queries.

Comment: A get an error here: List<Employee> myEmployee = new ArrayList<Employee>(); the type or namespace could not be found. Maybe the format is worng?

Comment: Have you imported all neccessary packages? I think you need `System.Collections.Generic` for generic collections to work (most IDE's would do this for you automatically).

Answer (score 0):

```
 Employee[] myEmployee = new Employee[15];
 //Fill your data
        double minS = myEmployee.ToList().Min(x => x.theSalary);
        var message =
            myEmployee.ToList()
                .Where(x => x.theSalary == minS)
                .Select(
                    x => string.Format("Lowest Salary: {0} {1} {2} {3}", x.theFirst, x.theLast, x.theID, x.theSalary));
```

Comment: Calling `ToList()` before every LinQ statement makes no sense and wastes performance. Also simply posting code without explanation is not very helpful.

Comment: ToList() because TC declared myEmployee as an array.

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev You can use LINQ functions on arrays as well.

Comment: LinQ works just fine on `T[]` since it is `IEnumerable<T>`.